# Creating CustomCells at Xcode5

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, xcode5

I was trying to create a CustomCell in Xcode 5 WITHOUT Storyboards (idk, was never my thing) but it seems it is not possible. Do anyone know how to solve it?

What I tried:

1. I have created a Cell in my ViewController nib and connected it with my Viewcontrollers .h. That worked well but it only works with more than ONE custom cell ([enter link for the tut](http://www.chriswrites.com/2012/06/how-to-use-custom-cells-with-table-views-in-xcode-5/)).
2. Same as before but now i connected it with a subclass of UITableViewCell but here the app crashes.

I have set the identifier of the cell but no way. Does anyone have an idea?

EDIT 1:
I rechecked my code. now I get this and i still think it xcode 5 based:

Code:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"HomeLoginCell";
GSCustomLoginCell *tableCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
NSLog(@"%d", indexPath.row);
NSLog(@"%@", [tableSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    tableCell.cellText.text = [tableSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    tableCell.cellIcon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"user_male-32"];
}else if(indexPath.row == 1){
    tableCell.cellText.text = [tableSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    tableCell.cellIcon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"enter-32"];
}

return tableCell;
```

}

Error:

```
2013-12-08 02:02:37.646 Group2Study[3921:60b] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2903.23/UITableView.m:6246
```

2013-12-08 02:02:37.648 Group2Study[3921:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2d72de83 0x37a8a6c7 0x2d72dd55 0x2e0d60af 0x2ffe5649 0x2fec3cf5 0x2ffe54b9 0x2ffe432d 0x2ff8c6cd 0x2ff8bef1 0x2feb2353 0x2fb38943 0x2fb34167 0x2fb63425 0x2ff2f18f 0x2ff2d7f9 0x2ff2ca37 0x2ff2c9bf 0x2ff2c957 0x2ff25459 0x2feb8397 0x2ff2c6a9 0x2ff2c17d 0x2febd581 0x2febaae5 0x2ff2582d 0x10e2a9 0x2ff22aad 0x2ff224f3 0x2ff1cb41 0x2feb7a07 0x2feb6cfd 0x2ff1c321 0x3239c76d 0x3239c357 0x2d6f8777 0x2d6f8713 0x2d6f6edf 0x2d661471 0x2d661253 0x2ff1b5c3 0x2ff16845 0x11c661 0x37f83ab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: Describing the crash would probably be helpful...

Comment: It crashed on [self.window makeKeyAndVisible] before i set my VC to the root window. It just says crashed on main thread..

Comment: Now... some code for context...?

Comment: Updated cuz I rechecked the code.

Comment: Why do you want to use xibs rather than a storyboard? A storyboard is Apple's "replacement" for xibs (in the sense that it's the new way to make views in iOS, not that you can't still use xibs either alone or in combination with storyboards). I can understand wanting to do everything in code, but if you're going to use IB anyway, why not go with storyboards?

Comment: i dont like the way how we move between vc on storyboards :S

Comment: @SaifDeen Why not?  Because it's too easy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
GSCustomLoginCell *tableCell = [tableView 
    dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if(!tableCell) {
   tableCell = [[GSCustomLoginCell alloc] init];
}
```

`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` only returns a cell when it's reusing a cell that's already been used.  So... the first time it tries to load your table, it's not recycling any cells and this method will return `nil`.  So, immediately after the call to this method, you should be checking whether it's `nil` or not, and if it is `nil`, instantiate a new object.

The error message explains that you're not returning a `UITableViewCell`, which is because, as I explained, `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` was returning `nil`.

Comment: facepalm.. I should go sleep... Well before i accept your answer, it works now but  my cells subviews (imageview & UILabel) are not displayed in the table. any idea?

Comment: In your question, I don't see an imageview or UILabel, unless you're referring to properties of your `GSCustomLoginCell`, in which case, you might need to post some code from the class before I could venture a guess.

Comment: Correct there properties, what code would you like to see? I just created the GSCustomLoginCell, connected the properties & synthesized the properties

Comment: What is `tableSource`?  And are you certain you put the images in your project correctly?  I mean... a million different things could be going wrong.

Comment: @SaifDeen, It would be better to register your nib (registerNib:forIdentifier:), then you don't need to check for cell == nil because it never will be. The problem with this answer is just using alloc init gets the class but never loads the nib.

Comment: tableSource is a Array of 2 Strings that i display on the Cells UILabel. The images are loaded right I checked it. @rdelmar yea how do I create one at xcode 5 for a uitableviewcell

Comment: @SaifDeen, create what? Just register you nib (in viewDidLoad is a good place), and then dequeue a cell with the same identifier you pass to that method.

Comment: I can create a nib for a Viewcontroller but not for a UITableViewCell

Comment: @SaifDeen, sorry, I thought you were creating your cell in a nib, but yes you can create a cell in a nib. Just create an empty user interface file, and drag a UITableViewCell into it. Modify it how you want, give it an identifier, and register that nib with the name of the file.

Comment: You said I have to register the nib, how can i do this?

Comment: @SaifDeen, look up the method, registerNib:forIdentifier:, in the UITableView Class Reference. How to use it is pretty self explanatory.